# Create dataframe of all combinations of a list

Tags: r

I have dataframe of integers from 1 to 900.

```
nodelist <- data.frame(node_id=seq(1:900))
```

I want to create a new dataframe of two columns (top, bottom) that has each combination of the vector nodelist. The top and bottom number cannot be the same. Something like:

```
top   bottom
1     2
1     3
1     4
2     1
2     3
```

I have tried cross() and expand.grid() to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid` and remove the rows where two columns have same values.

```
nodelist <- data.frame(node_id=1:9)
subset(expand.grid(nodelist$node_id, nodelist$node_id), Var1 != Var2)


#   Var1 Var2
#2     2    1
#3     3    1
#4     4    1
#5     5    1
#6     6    1
#7     7    1
#8     8    1
#9     9    1
#10    1    2
#...
#...
```

Or with `crossing`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

crossing(setNames(nodelist, 'top'), setNames(nodelist, 'bottom')) %>%
     filter(top != bottom)
```

Comment: simply doing pairs <- expand.grid(nodelist, nodelist) gives me a df of 1 obs. of 2 variables, which is not correct.

Comment: @otterdog2000 If I use your `nodelist` and do `pairs <- subset(expand.grid(nodelist, nodelist), Var1 != Var2)` it gives me 809100 rows and 2 columns

Comment: I'm sorry, my nodelist is actually a dataframe of 1 column name node_id, which is that sequence. I will correct in the question.

Comment: @otterdog2000 If it's a column of the dataframe you need to use `subset(expand.grid(df$nodelist, df$nodelist), Var1 != Var2)` where `df` is the dataframe and `nodelist` is column name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option by removing one element from the vector one at a time:

```
nodelist <- seq(1:4)

data.frame(
    top=rep(nodelist, each=length(nodelist) - 1L),
    bottom=c(sapply(seq_along(nodelist), function(i) nodelist[-i]))
)
```

output:

```
   top bottom
1    1      2
2    1      3
3    1      4
4    2      1
5    2      3
6    2      4
7    3      1
8    3      2
9    3      4
10   4      1
11   4      2
12   4      3
```